# How can ı fix my tensorflow installation cudart64_110.dll not found error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried everything from start to finish. I downloaded the necessary files such as Cuda Toolkit and Cudnnn and added the bin , include .. paths of each to the environment variables. I have also updated the latest c++ redistributable (Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019) with the latest versions, but I still can't solve my problem and ı still get this below error.
have a nice day

2021-08-26 23:34:03.118745: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-08-26 23:34:03.122765: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Comment: The version of Tensorflow seems to require CUDA 11.0 Is that the version you have installed?

Comment: Yes, ı had installed it. Also, there's something I forgot to mention. That's it, CUDA/v.11.2/bin finds cudart64_110.dll in this path, but somehow it can't load it.

Comment: Could you please specify your Python, Tensorflow versions and also type of GPU you are using to understand the problem. Thank You.

Comment: Python 3.8.10  , tensorflow 2.6.0 , GPU = GeForce GTX 1650 Tı